# Is there catkin support for atlas_msgs and osrf_msgs?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I tried to build a catkin package that depends on atlas_msgs and osrf_msgs.

I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package atlas_msgs.

  Set atlas_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for atlas_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

    atlas_msgsConfig.cmake
    atlas_msgs-config.cmake
```

I looked in the bitbucket groovy branch of drcsim, but don't see those files there either.

We are developing in groovy, and would like to catkinize where we can.  Is there a recommended approach?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1594/is-there-catkin-support-for-atlas_msgs-and-osrf_msgs?/) by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 298 on 2013-03-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thanks, [ticketed](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/143/catkin-ize-ros-packages-in-drcsim-and), will work on getting it in to drcsim 2.3.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0